# Where's the first attestation of the distinction between "hardcore" hentai and "softcore" ecchi?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, japanese

The Wikipedia articles on both "Hentai" and "Ecchi" (the "Western usage" in particular) do not provide much clarity on this. *Etchi* in Japanese as far as I can tell is about as broad as *hentai* and covers some hardcore stuff as well. Neither is used to describe a  porno genre, but only aspects of porn, like say a person, a character, a scene, a plot point, etc. The artificial distinction in western usage between "hardcore" *hentai* and "softcore" *etchi* seems unfounded, though the "Ecchi" article does note:

> For instance, if a young woman were to call a young man e(t/c)chi, that might be construed as flirting, whereas hentai sounds more like condemnation.

This sounds to me like a mere euphemistic abbreviation, like how you'd say "SA" or the "R-word" in English, therefore not a strong explanation.

The "Hentai" article notes:

> The Anime Movie Guide, published in 1997, defines "ecchi" (エッチ, etchi) as the initial sound of hentai (i.e., the name of the letter H, as pronounced in Japanese); it included that ecchi was "milder than hentai".

I'm not sure if this is the first attestation, and it still does not elaborate on the rationale.

Keep in mind that both *hentai* and *etchi* are Japanese words. This is not comparable to the distinctions between "comic" and "manga," and "cartoon" and "anime." While there's no genuine difference between the words in each pair in Japanese, the latter in each is distinctly Japanese. It's almost like how you'd call Franco-Belgian comics "bande dessinée" (if you want to sound pompous, that is).

So where is the first attestation of the distinction between these two words? And did the person or people who made that distinction provide any justification?

**IMPORTANT:** Here are some useful links about "hentai" as an ENGLISH word:

[Why Japanese Don't Know What "Hentai" Is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKK8TfAA5XQ)

[Do Japanese People Watch Hentai? (Interview)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=ZahxIvEBw74)

The only meanings Japanese people know are, obviously, Japanese meanings. They don't think of "hentai" as a genre, let alone a specific genre of Japanese hardcore manga/anime porn. This usage is entirely ENGLISH. So to smart alecks who are quick at typing before thinking, this question is NOT about Japanese.

Just to drive home the point, [the Japanese Wikipedia article corresponding to the English "Hentai"](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%98%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4) is very explicit about its English usage. They spell it with katakana (ヘンタイ) and Roman letters (HENTAI), which is precisely what you do not do to a true Sino-Japanese word like 変態. One section in this article plainly explains how "HENTAI" is not a Japanese word, and actual Japanese alternatives include ポルノ ("porn"), 18禁 ("forbidden for under 18") and 成人 ("adult").

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152046/discussion-on-question-by-vun-hugh-vaw-wheres-the-first-attestation-of-the-dist); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.